# How to convert list of images into list of numbers in python? TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Image'

Tags: python, list, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm writing a code to load images and resize them, after that I modified that code, splitting those resized images into three categories; train, test and validation (according to ratios). Then I got this error, "`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Image`'" after adding this line (15): `img.load()` to eliminate error: `ValueError: seek of closed file`.

this is code.

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage
import split_folders
import os, os.path
import numpy as np
import shutil
from scipy.misc import imresize

def loadImages(path):
    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        with open(os.path.join(path, image), 'rb') as i:
            img = PImage.open(i)
            img.load()
            loadedImages.append(img)
    return loadedImages

path = "./Inputs/"
imgs = loadImages(path)

#resizing
imgs = [img.resize((160,80), PImage.ANTIALIAS) for img in imgs]
print(imgs)

# split folders
np.random.shuffle(imgs)  # now this list is shuffled
train, validate, test = np.split(imgs, [int(.7*len(imgs)), int(.85*len(imgs))])


print("loading images to Train folder")
print(train)
destination = "./Outputs/train/*.png"
# shutil.copy(np.array(train),destination)
# a = PImage.fromarray(train)
# a.save(destination,".png")
# train = PImage.fromarray(train).convert('RGB')
# train.save(destination,'PNG')


print("loading images to Test folder")
print(test)

print("loading images to Validation folder")
print(validate)
```

this is traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thisuri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line51, in _wrapfunc
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'swapaxes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thisuri/Documents/Re-Train_OCR/retrain_script.py", line 28, in <module>
    train, validate, test = np.split(imgs, [int(.7*len(imgs)), int(.85*len(imgs))])
  File "/home/thisuri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 785, in split
    res = array_split(ary, indices_or_sections, axis)
  File "/home/thisuri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 702, in array_split
    sary = _nx.swapaxes(ary, axis, 0)
  File "/home/thisuri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line549, in swapaxes
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'swapaxes', axis1, axis2)
  File "/home/thisuri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line61, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "/home/thisuri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line41, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/thisuri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 501, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Image'
```

Any Solution?

Comment: It doesn't look like Numpy arrays and array operations like split work with complex objects like PIL Images. You probably need to convert your images into lists of numbers that you plan to train on before running your split. If you are trying, however, to just break them out to re-save them, you are probably better off just using traditional python slices (e.g. imgs[0:a], imgs[a:b],imgs[b:] ).

Comment: How can I convert these images to lists of numbers, I tried but I failed. @Nikolaj

Comment: You can call the getdata() method on each Image: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata

Answer (score 1):

this could be one method, Keep validation set in different folder altogether. Split will happen when you will fit model (at the end of this code). An example here.

```
datadir = "C:/Users..."
categories = ['A','B','C']
img_size = 200
img_size_y= 420
from tqdm import tqdm    
training_data = []

    def create_training_data():
        for category in categories:
            path = os.path.join(datadir, category)
            class_num = categories.index(category)
            for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):
                try:
                    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_size,img_size_y))
                    training_data.append([new_array,class_num])
                except Exception as e:
                    pass

    create_training_data()


import random 
random.shuffle(training_data)

x = []
y = []
for features, label in training_data:
    x.append(features)
    y.append(label)

x =np.array(x).reshape(-1, img_size, img_size_y, 1)

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import time

dense_layers = [0,1,2]
layer_sizes = [32,64,128]
conv_layers =[1,3,5,10]

for dense_layer in dense_layers:
    for layer_size in layer_sizes:
        for conv_layer in conv_layers:
            Name= "{}-conv-{}-nodes-{}-dense-{}".format(conv_layer, layer_size,dense_layer,
                                                       int(time.time()))
            print(Name)
            tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(name)) 
            model = Sequential()

            model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3,3), input_shape = x.shape[1:]))
            model.add(Activation('relu'))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

            for l in range (conv_layer-1):
                model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3,3)))
                model.add(Activation('relu'))
                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

            model.add(Flatten())
            for l in range(dense_layer):
                model.add(Dense(layer_size))
                model.add(Activation('relu'))

            model.add(Dense(1))
            model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
            model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy",
                         optimizer="adam",
                         metrics=['accuracy'])

            model.fit(x,y, batch_size=2, epochs= 10, validation_split=0.3, callbacks=[tensorboard]) 
            #here is you split happening for test
```

Comment: thanks @Rimjhim, but I want to do this without using ML frameworks, using only python

Answer (score 0):

You can convert PIL images into numpy arrays. Copying an example from https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray -

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
im = Image.open('hopper.jpg')
a = np.asarray(im)
```